# pass a string with white space in javascript

Tags: php

Hello I have a php code which by echo calls the javascript function `expand(txt)` with the parameter 'txt'

```
echo "<div onclick=javascript:expand('$hint1')>$valueX</div>";


function expand(txt)
{

document.getElementById("targetDiv").value=txt;

}
```

my problem is that this script works only if the '$hint1' is a string without white space, example if $hint="car" everything works but if $hint="red car" the javascript is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does it do exactly? Updates a DIV with the text of 'car' or red car for example? Elaborate a bit more please....

Comment: What is the *exact error* or *symptom*? And What does the *HTML look like*? (The PHP is only relevant if the generated HTML is "wrong"; using this will very easily show what is wrong -- an HTML validator will help where eyes fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
echo "<div onclick=javascript:expand('$hint1')>$valueX</div>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<div onclick=\"expand('$hint1')\">$valueX</div>";
```

the onclick-event has to be in "" and you don't need the javascript:-label (but the last one shouldn't make a difference, it's just senseless)

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML is at fault.

Your PHP outputs:

```
<div onclick=javascript:expand('red car')>sometext</div>
```

which is clearly broken.

Also, `javascript:` is redundant here; this is not a URI, but a Javascript event handler.

Make your PHP output this instead:

```
<div onclick="expand('red car')">sometext</div>
```

I'll leave the specifics as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `innerHTML` property to **change** the content of a `div`.

```
document.getElementById("targetDiv").innerHTML = txt;
```

Also make sure you properly **quote** attributes in your markup.

```
echo "<div onclick=\"expand('$hint1')\">$valueX</div>";
```

*JS Note:* If you really want to **append** some content to an element, you better off with a `textNode`:

```
function expand(el, text) {
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}

// and your markup becomes:
echo "<div onclick=\"expand(this, '$hint1')\">$valueX</div>";
```

Comment: you don't need the "javascript:" declaration as onclick is already a JS event handle...

Comment: @Jamie - Correct, but it won't hurt either. :)